# Can tumble and jump be done at the same time?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills

Suppose we have a creature with a base move speed of 50ft.
Suppose that creature is standing on a small platform and wishes to jump across a gap 15ft wide to another small platform.
Also suppose that the square the creature is initially standing in and/or squares along the path to the other platform are threatened by an enemy.

Can a jump be combined with an acrobatics check to avoid attacks of opportunity?

If so, what would the bonus from move speed to the jump check be? +8 because the creature is 20ft above 30ft speed, or -4 because the creature would be reduced to moving at half speed to avoid the +10 to the DC for the avoiding attacks of opportunity check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An acrobatics check to avoid an AoO can be combined with other forms of movement, such as balancing, jumping, as well as climb, fly and swim. An acrobatics check is part of a move action, and not a distinct action by itself.

It would be two checks, the first to avoid the AoO, which would be based on the creature threatening CMD. The second would be a DC 15 check(with a ten foot running start) or 30(without) with a +8 to the roll(just because you are moving half speed, does not effect your actual base speed which is what provides the bonus). In addition, an often overlooked additional penalty for those making the jump without any movement prior is the jump distance is halved.